# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on vercel after deploying Nextjs App

Tags: internationalization, next.js, i18next, vercel

I deployed my **nextjs** app to Vercel and it was a success.

I can see a preview of the website and even the log saying it works well.

But i try to access the website via the default Vercel domain :

> https://tly-nextjs.vercel.app/

I get an **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.

**I do not have this problem locally.**

I tried :

- Disabling a language redirect that I use (/en for english folks, and / for french people).
- Disabling the language detector of **i18next**.

But none of these solutions changed anything.
Any ideas ?

i18n.js file

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Cache from 'i18next-localstorage-cache';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';



const fallbackLng = ['fr']; 
const availableLanguages = ['fr', 'en'];

const en = require('./locales/en/common.json');
const fr = require('./locales/fr/common.json');

const options = {
  order: ['querystring', 'navigator'],
  lookupQuerystring: 'lng'
}

const cacheOptions = {
  // turn on or off
  enabled: true,

  // prefix for stored languages
  prefix: 'i18next_res_',

  // expiration
  expirationTime: 365*24*60*60*1000,

  // language versions
  //versions: {}
}

i18n
  .use(Cache)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    cache: cacheOptions,
    fallbackLng: fallbackLng,
    debug: true,
    detection: options,
    supportedLngs: availableLanguages,
    nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true,
    resources: {
      en: {translation: en},
      fr: {translation: fr},
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    react: {
      wait: true,
      useSuspense: true,
    },
  });


export default i18n;
```

My change Language function :

```js
const changeLanguageInHouse = (lang, bool) => {
    setLoading(true);

    i18next.changeLanguage(lang).then((t) => {
      setLanguage(lang);
      bake_cookie("langChoice", lang);
      setLoading(false);

      if (bool === true) {
        var newUrl2 = (lang === "fr" ? "" : "/en") + asPath;

        window.location.replace(newUrl2);
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: You need to add a minimal reproducible example. Your answer mentioned a solution that would be impossible for another user to find, given the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed all my getInitialProps to getServerSideProps

and realised I was doing a redirect on response :

```js
res.writeHead(301, { Location: "/" })
```

I just delete it.
And now I don't have this endless redirect.

Answer (score 2):

What happend at your server is following:

You enter https://tly-nextjs.vercel.app/ and it is redirected to /en with HTTP-Status-Code 307 (Temporary Redirect).

And /en redirect with 301 (Permanent Redirect) to /.

You can reproduce this by open the Browser-Dev-Tools and have a look at the `Network` Tab.

It might be, that you have some kind of url-rewriting activated at your server, which redirect everything to your domain-root.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helps!
I asked Vercel about it, but they will take 1 week to answer...

Do you think this is something i can change in my code, or maybe by using a custom domain?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a public repo available for this? Here is how it worked for me.

Try changing the order of the locales and the default locale (not sure this helps, but it changed something for me. Undocumented if that is the case!)
So I put the default locale first (which is nl for me) in both the `locales` array and the `domains` array.

Let me know if that helps!

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    localeDetection: false,
    // These are all the locales you want to support in
    // your application
    locales: ['nl', 'en'],
    // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
    // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
    defaultLocale: 'nl',
    // This is a list of locale domains and the default locale they
    // should handle (these are only required when setting up domain routing)
    domains: [
      {
        domain: 'example.be',
        defaultLocale: 'nl',
      },
      {
        domain: 'example.com',
        defaultLocale: 'en',
      },
    ],
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't change anything. I just tried it. As I said, my code works perfectly locally, i have this redirect problem when i deploy it on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Doing this worked for me...
https://vercel.com/guides/resolve-err-too-many-redirects-when-using-cloudflare-proxy-with-vercel

I think it's the actual solution to the cause of the problem rather than a bandage!

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with my problem at the time. See my response below

Comment: link is broken. please write a summary of the solution first otherwise when the link is broken like in this case, there's no information to go about

Comment: https://vercel.com/guides/resolve-err-too-many-redirects-when-using-cloudflare-proxy-with-vercel

Official Vercel Guide!
What it points to is when Cloudflare points to Vercel, it needs to make sure that the SSL mode is set to either Full or Full (Strict) otherwise there's too many redirects.